# Find Text in a Named Range

Tags: google-apps-script, indexof

I'm trying to get the row or index number of a string That is put in by the user. I retrieve the data in an array using spreadsheet.getRangeByName("Symbols").getValues(). The problem is it doesn't retrieve the data as strings it retrieves it as an array. So the result is an array of arrays. I wanted to use the function indexOf(result.getResponseText().toUpperCase()), but that doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
  var aSymbols = spreadsheet.getRangeByName("Symbols").getValues();
  Logger.log(aSymbols);
  var row = aSymbols.indexOf(result.getResponseText().toUpperCase());
  Logger.log(row);
```

And the results are:

### [[ ], [XOM], [PLTR], [IBM], [VWAGY], [LIT], [ ], []]

I tried adding "[" and "]" to the search string, but that didn't work. I also tried using spreadsheet.getRangeByName("Symbols").getValues().toString(), but it returned 1 big long string. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution:

You can use `findIndex()` to get the index in 2D array:

```
  var aSymbols = spreadsheet.getRangeByName("Symbols").getValues();
  Logger.log(aSymbols);
  var row = aSymbols.findIndex(function check(e) {return e[0] === result.getResponseText().toUpperCase()});
  Logger.log(row);
```

### Reference:

[findIndex()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp)

Comment: Very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
 let aSymbolsArray = aSymbols.flat();
```

This will convert the double Array into a Array of strings.

```
function test(){
  
  let aSymbols = [['' ], ['XOM'], ['PLTR'], ['IBM'], ['VWAGY'], ['LIT'], ['' ], ['']];
  console.log(aSymbols);
    //
    //   [ 'XOM' ],
    //   [ 'PLTR' ],
    //   [ 'IBM' ],
    //   [ 'VWAGY' ],
    //   [ 'LIT' ],
    //   [ '' ],
    //   [ '' ] ]
    //
  
  let aSymbolsArray = aSymbols.flat();
  console.log(aSymbolsArray);
      //
      // [ '', 'XOM', 'PLTR', 'IBM', 'VWAGY', 'LIT', '', '' ]
      //
}
```